# Safari Toolbar Icons Blank

Tags: safari

Regularly, after some time using Safari, 3rd party icons in Safari toolbar become blank.

Restarting Safari fixes the problem, but after some time it happens again.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are there any relevant log messages in Console / system.log?

Comment: Did you try to disable extensions and observe Safari's behavior then?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me as well. Only 3rd party buttons go blank.

1. Go to Preferences > Extensions
2. Turn Extensions OFF
3. Turn Extensions ON

The icons should come back.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a valid bug with the Safari browser. You can [file a report here.](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is a Safari bug? Might be a problem with one of the 3rd party extensions as well.